# Can't install neo4j on Fedora

Tags: neo4j, repository, fedora, rpm

I am using Fedora 29 and want to install Neo4j on it. I am following [the instructions provided on their website](http://yum.neo4j.org/stable/?_ga=2.153154040.151173883.1547039720-1752660589.1547039720)

It asks me to add a repo. I have done it, and given all the permissions to the repo file as well. When I finally run the command `yum install neo4j` or `sudo yum install neo4j`, I get the following error:

```
Warning: failed loading '/etc/yum.repos.d/neo4j.repo', skipping.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:01 ago on Wednesday 09 January 2019 08:53:37 PM IST.
No match for argument: neo4j
```

Can any neo4j expert here working on Fedora provide me reference on how to install neo4j on Fedora properly?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it cannot read it.

- What are the permissions on that file?
- Is there a typo in the file?
- Did you copy it from a Windows box and it needs `dos2unix` run on it?